# Displace modifier doesn't work as intender in blender 2.82

Tags: modeling, modifiers, displacement

i've been folowing this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EqLyGsu3AA doing things exactly as he does.
but on the 10th second my model looks entirely diferent. 
It looks like this 
http://puu.sh/FhMoz/d426fbb061.jpg
And it only after i crank the strength of the displace way up, before that i just like a smooth ball. I am doing that in blender 2.82.
When i try to do it in older versions like 2.8 it work just fine there.
How do i fix it?